# When i'm given like "IndexError", how wouid i have to do?

Tags: python-3.7

First, I tried to write like below,

```
import sys    
name = sys.argv[1]    
print("Hello, " + name +"!")
```

But, I couldn't complete it.
about this part which is `name = sys.argv[1]`,
it gave me `IndexError : list index out of range`

Answer (score 0):

It means that you should supply an argument to the script, like `python script.py Kohei`. When launched this way, sys.argv[0] is the script name, and arguments supplied start with sys.argv[1] and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
name = sys.argv[0]
value = sys.argv[1]
print("Hello, " + name +"!")
print("Hello, " + value +"!")
```

**IndexError:** list index out of range, this is because you are only providing one argument while running you python script from shell or cmd.

Suppose, you have saved your python file with a name like **test.py** and in order to run this script you have to run a command `python test.py` on `command prompt` or `terminal`. here, is the concept of **command line arguments**, while reading the command after the word `python` or we can say that `token`-"python" we have space seperated values which are treated as command line arguments. the space seperated word or token or arguments can be retrive from `sys.argv` as a `list`. and when you do `sys.argv[0]` we will get the output as `test.py` which is the command line argument or our file name. if we run command `python test.py testing` we will get testing as the output of `sys.argv[1]`.

you are recieving error IndexError: list index out of range because you are running command like `python test.py` so we have only one command line argument test.py at index 0, and we didn't have any value for index 1.